# How did I eliminate my own steel trap as Junkrat?

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes while playing Deathmatch, I'll see a prompt telling me that I've gotten credit for eliminating my own Steel Trap or Concussion Mine while playing as Junkrat.

[image: Eliminating own Junkrat trap]

I've had this happen to me 2 or 3 times, but only while playing as Junkrat in Deathmatch mode. I haven't been able to figure out how this happened, or how to prevent it.

This doesn't seem to be a bug with Junkrat's grenade launcher. When I tried firing directly at the trap, the grenades didn't do any damage.

**How is it possible to eliminate my own Steel Trap as Junkrat?**

Comment: Sounds like some sort of bug.

Comment: Is it possible that JeffTheTree was currently _stuck_ in your trap when you killed him? I.e. when a trap closes, it "belongs" to whoever is caught by the trap, but the name of the trap is fixed once it's laid down (thus carrying your name, even though the ownership shifted). This makes sense from a game building perspective, because the trap and the trapped can be considered as a single game object for the duration of the trap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug currently present with deployables in Free-For-All Deathmatch. Since there are no teams, a player's own deployables such as Junkrat's trap and Orisa's shield sometimes behave oddly, such as Junkrat's trap being destroyed by his own Concussion Mine and Orisa's shield blocking the pull effect from her alternate fire. There's nothing you can do except wait for a patch to fix it.

[This link](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758477228) to Overwatch Patch notes for 1.15 confirms the following bug in FFA;

> - Junkrat can destroy his own Steel Trap with a Concussion Mine

Comment: Has Blizzard acknowledged this anywhere? At the moment, your answer seems like speculation.

Comment: I'm requesting some official source that states this is a bug. Otherwise, this is just your opinion.

Comment: ...no, having your own deployables work against you is not proper behaviour and definitely a bug. Official source will be patch notes once it's fixed. It's not an opinion.

Comment: No, it certainly isn't proper behavior, I'm not disagreeing there. But at best, your answer is just speculation about being a bug without some sort of official backing from the developers. Some sort of acknowledgment that it's a bug, anything. That doesn't seem like a mountainous request.

Comment: [If this didn't exist](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758477228) my answer would be just as valid.